# Connect signal to function with arguments (Python)

Tags: qgis, python, qt

I have this function in Python that take 2 arguments:

```
     def niveau(controName,idNiveau):
              ........
```

I want to connect it to this signal:
`QObject.connect(dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, 'buttonBox'), SIGNAL('accepted()'),niveau(control,1))`
But I got this error: `Qt signal is not callable`.

Does someone could help me please?

Comment: I presume this is for QGis? You might get a better answer faster for PyQT questions on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `lambda` or `functools.partial` to pass a argument to a slot.

Try this

```
from functools import partial

buttonbox = dialog.findChild(QDialogButtonBox, 'buttonBox')
buttonBox.accepted.connect(partial(niveau, control, 1))
```

Information about `functools.partial` can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331726/how-does-the-functools-partial-work-in-python)

Note: Don't use the `QObject.connect` sytanx anymore as it's outdated and just looks crap. The new style is `{object}.{signal}.connect({slot})`